# Custom messages while publishing and using storage extension

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, publishing

Scenario: (In SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1)

We have a storage extension which indexes the Component Presentation in SOLR, now If due to some reason this indexing is failed, we want to rollback the publishing and emit a Failure status to CME GUI with a Custom message.

What we have achieved so far and what is the issue:

We are able to rollback and emit the failure to GUI successfully. We sent the custom message as well but it get displayed twice on the CME GUI along with some default message from Tridion.

What we need:

We want to show only non-redundant custom message that we sent through storage extension.
Is it possible to control this behaviour and is it possible to show a specific custom message on rollback and failure through storage extension. Did any one in the group come across any out of the box or tailor made solution.

**Per Bart's suggestion**
Below is the code I am using for sending back the custom messages in the Storage Extension written for Dynamic Component Presentation:

```
public void create(ComponentPresentation itemToCreate, ComponentPresentationTypeEnum componentPresentationType)
    throws StorageException
    {

      try
      {
           .. Code for Indexing the Data in SOLR and capturing any error..

           if(<Indexing is successful>) {do nothing}
           else
           {
              throw new StorageException(<Custom Error Message>);
           }

      } 

      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        throw new StorageException(<Custom Error Message>); 
      }  

    }
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that OOTB this is not possible - your custom error messages will not be passed back to the CM. I will double check this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Nuno; we are able to pass back the custom error messages back to CM via Storage Extension, the issue is that message is displayed multiple times.

Comment: @PankajGaur perhaps you can share some more detail (like code) on what is, and how you are sending the messages back? It would make sense to me that that is responsible for the duplication somehow, and with more information we can hopefully come to an answer for this question.

Comment: @BartKoopman - I have already added some indicative code in this regard. Let me know if any specific code I need to add

Comment: @PankajGaur can you differentiate which of the error messages are being returned, is it the one in your `else` or the `catch` clause?

Comment: @BartKoopman As specified by the condition, both these messages are getting returned to the CME. Else message specified that Publishing has gone fine but there is some issue with the Indexing Process and error message is relevant to this and is returned in this scenario; whereas the catch specified the error message to returned in case of either there is any unexpected error in the publishing process and is returned accordingly

Comment: @PankajGaur so you are getting both messages back as duplicates, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes That's correct, we are getting both the message as duplicate on CME; I will try re-produce a Error Scenario in Publishing and will try to put up a screen shot for the same.

Comment: @PankajGaur are you getting both the error messages from the else and the catch statement, or are these different messages?

Comment: @PankajGaur is it possible you are getting duplicate messages because the create method is getting called twice? Maybe there are 2 component presentations being deployed?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Quirjin, However, I have tested with in a fresh publication having only one component presentation only. But it still behaves the same :(

Answer (score 4):

Your first thrown exception will be caught in your catch(), as you are catching all Exceptions. You could be more specific in the kinds of exceptions you are catching - or at least make an exception for StorageExceptions, like this:

```java
public void create(ComponentPresentation itemToCreate, ComponentPresentationTypeEnum componentPresentationType)
    throws StorageException
    {

      try
      {
           .. Code for Indexing the Data in SOLR and capturing any error..

           if(<Indexing is successful>) {do nothing}
           else
           {
              throw new StorageException(<Custom Error Message>);
           }

      } 
      catch(StorageException ex)
      {
        throw ex;
      }  
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        throw new StorageException(<Custom Error Message>); 
      }  

    }
```

Comment: This makes sense to me...I will try this and see if this is the issue.
+1 for the valuable suggestion though.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you're showing messages via the Event System. If you subscribed to an event that encompasses two or more child events, for example `PublishEventArgs` is a parent for  `PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs` and `SetPublishStateEventArgs`, then your logic would be triggered in instances of both of the child events. This would explain why you see the error message twice. You need to narrow down and subscribe to the most specific event so that it is the only one you show a message on.

If you share your code/which event(s) you've subscribed to, to fire the message, we can help further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nickoli, but I am not using Event System at all but using Storage Extension. I might have an idea about why they are coming twice even if I try to override directly at the storage layer, but I am looking for a solution to overcome this.